# Tool Tip Character Limit -title attribute

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have a label in which I show a string of 30 characters. If the string exceeds I break at 30 followed by ellipsis (...) and set the title attribute of that label with actual text.

So if my text was say 100 characters then my label would show 30characters ... but on hover of which i can read 100 characters.

Problem:
There seems to be a limit for tool tip at certain point (around 400-500) due to which my purpose fails.

Is there any way I can show any character long text on my label tool tip ?

Comment: What code are you using to handle your tool tips?

Comment: Title attribute of label html element. Although I do create this label dynamically using javascript and also do set title using js .
$(labelID).title = "My 4000 character long text";

Comment: Instead of these you could use jquery tool tip [Link for jquery tool tip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: does jquery tool tip have no limitation on length of text

Comment: @Zohaib Tooltip max length (for title element) would be dependent on the browser also w3c standard notes a soft limit of 64, see [here](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html). Jquery tooltip is html so no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery tooltip for this case. You can also use images in tooltip like [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-add-icons-and-title-to-jquery-tooltip/) sample. And [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) is the documentation for jquery-ui tooltip.

Using tooltip should be like this,

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip();
```

Comment: LInk you shared not right